# Linear operators in $L^\infty$ and convergence in weak*-topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

I tried to solve the following problem and want to know if my approach is correct and some help in order to finish. Thanks.

Let $V = L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$  equipped with the norm $\left\lVert \cdot\right\rVert_\infty$ and $V^*$ its dual space.

For any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, define $l_f :V\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$l_f(g) = \int f\cdot g \,dx \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall g\in V$$

1. Show that $l_f\in V^*$.

**Proof:**

Let $g,h\in V$ and $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$l_f(\lambda g+\mu h) = \int f\cdot (\lambda g +\mu h)\,dx = \int \lambda\, f\cdot g\,dx\,+\,\int \mu\, f\cdot h\,dx=\lambda\,l_f(g)\,+\,\mu\, l_f(h)$$
Hence $l_f$ is linear.

We now look at $\left\lVert l_f \right\rVert_{op}$.
By definition,

$$\left\lVert l_f \right\rVert_{op}=\sup\big\{\lvert l_f(g)\rvert : \left\lVert g \right\rVert_{\infty}\leq 1\big\}$$

Then we notice that

$$\bigg\lvert\int f\cdot g\,dx\bigg\rvert\leq \int\lvert f\cdot g\rvert \,dx\leq \left\lVert g\right\rVert_{\infty}\int\lvert f\rvert\,dx = \left\lVert g\right\rVert_{\infty}\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{1}$$

It follows that, when $\left\lVert g\right\rVert_{\infty}, \leq 1$, we have
$$\left\lVert l_f \right\rVert_{op}\leq\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{1}<\infty$$

Hence, $l_f$ is bounded and it belongs to $V^*$.
$\square$

2. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $l_n:V\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$l_n(g) =\frac{1}{2n}\int_{-n}^n g\,dx$$

Show that there exists an $l\in V^*$ and a subsequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $l_{n_k}\xrightarrow{\text{w*}} l$.

**Proof:**

First notice that $\left\lVert l_n \right\rVert_{op}\leq 1$, indeed, by definition
$$\left\lVert l_n \right\rVert_{op} = \sup\big\{ \lvert l_n(g)\rvert : \left\lVert g \right\rVert_{\infty}\leq 1\big\}$$

Now

$$\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{2n}\int_{-n}^n g\,dx \bigg\rvert \leq  \frac{1}{2n} \int_{-n}^n\lvert g\rvert\,dx \leq \left\lVert g \right\rVert_{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} (n-(-n)) =\left\lVert g \right\rVert_{\infty}$$

By above, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $l_n \in \overline{B} {}^* = \bigg\{f\in V^* : \left\lVert f \right\rVert_{op}\leq 1\bigg\}$.

By the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem, we know that $\overline{B} {}^*$ is weak* compact. And hence $l_n$ shoud have a convergent subsequence in the weak* topology.

However, I don't know how to define this $l\in V^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $l_n$ does not admit a convergent subsequence. The Banach-Alaoglu theorem states that the sequence has an accumulation point, but it does not imply a convergent subsequence. The proof is below.

Assume such subsequence exists. We can extract from $n_k$ another subsequence $m_k$ such that $${m_{2k}\over m_{2k+1}}\to 0,\quad {m_{2k+1}\over m_{2k+2}}\to 0$$ Define the function $g$ by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \ \ \,\ m_{2k}\le |x|\le m_{2k+1}\\
0 & m_{2k+1}<|x|<m_{2k+2}\end{cases}$$
Then
$${1\over 2m_{2k+1}}\int\limits_{-m_{2k+1}}^{m_{2k+1}}g(x)\,dx\ge {2(m_{2k+1}-m_{2k}) \over 2m_{2k+1}}=1-{m_{2k}\over m_{2k+1} }\to 1$$
On the other hand
$${1\over 2m_{2k+2}}\int\limits_{-m_{2k+2}}^{m_{2k+2}}g(x)\,dx={1\over 2m_{2k+2}}\int\limits_{-m_{2k+1}}^{m_{2k+1}}g(x)\,dx
\le {m_{2k+1}\over m_{2k+2}}\to 0$$
This shows that the limit of
$${1\over m_k}\int\limits_{-m_k}^{m_k}g(x)\,dx$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you have to define it explicitly. Just show its existence.

It seems to me that the whole point of this exercise is the fact that the topological dual of $L^{\infty}$ is not $L^1$, but it is actually bigger. The functional $l$ that is constructed via Banach-Alaoglu is an example of element in the dual, outside of $L^1$. In other words, there is no $f\in L^1$ such that $l=l_f$.

Comment: I thought so too, but after reading my proof, it kind of felt incomplete without this $l$. But thank you a lot for reading my question and for your answer!